# Short story with alien vampire hunter on Earth

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

Looking for a short story.

Background was there were a ship of alien viruses(vampires) intended for a night planet that had crashed on Earth long ago and were accidentally activated by radio transmissions of the developing human race.

Plot is a vampire hunter (also alien but humanoid) is sent to exterminate the vampires. The story takes place in a building that is surrounded and force-fielded off where the hunter exterminated the vampires.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  You might be able to improve this question by checking out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for writing a good story-id question.  Please [edit] in any extra details that you recall.

Answer (score 3):

This is "[Infestation](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?850075)" by [Garth Nix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garth_Nix), first published in *[The Starry Rift](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?254906)*, edited by Jonathan Strahan, 2008. I read it in *[To Hold the Bridge](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?515400)*.

Starts with a group of vampire hunters gathering to clean out a newly found infestation of vampires. There is a secure perimeter guarded by soldiers, and only licensed vampire hunters are allowed to enter. Most of the hunters are amateurs, but the narrator is a professional.

Over the course of the story we learn some of the history of the vampires and the narrator. In short, in an alien war, a team of vampires was landed on the wrong planet (Earth). The narrator is an alien whose mission (punishment) is to eradicate the infestation from Earth.

THere is a copy online at https://talesofmytery.blogspot.com/2013/02/garth-nix-infestation.html

Comment: What about the viruses? Were the vampires viruses, or were they infected with viruses, or what?

Comment: I don't have the story, but if you want to listen to it, there's a reading of it here: http://escapepod.org/2009/10/29/ep222-infestation/  (You can skip the first 2 minutes of intro.)

Comment: I can't find my copy right now. But I think it was nanotech, rather than viruses. Nevertheless, people could be infected and so recruited as junior vampires.